# Can't change value of a XML file

Tags: c#, xml

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(@"MainXML.xml");
XmlElement node1 = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("main/variables/isbd") as XmlElement;
node1.InnerText = "true";
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<main>
<variables>
<isbd>false</isbd>
</variables>
</main>
```

I can run the code without errors, but "isbd" is still "false". Its the first time I'm using XML files, please help

Comment: Are you sure you're modifying the file you think you are, and not a copy in the build folder?

Comment: could you please show your xml file?

Comment: @er-shoaib I added XML file

Comment: @D3DS1R, just add `xmlDoc.Save(@"MainXML.xml");` below to `node1.InnerText = "true";`

Comment: @er-shoaib I did but I started getting error "System.Xml.XmlException"

Comment: Could you please add full exception message here, so i can try to resolve

Comment: @er-shoaib The message was in Turkish, so I tried to translate it. "Root-level data is invalid. Line 1, position 1. '"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try **Load()** and **Save()** methods.

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlPath = @"MainXML.xml";
xmldoc.Load(xmlPath);

var node1 = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("main/variables/isbd");
node1.InnerText = "true";

xmldoc.Save(xmlPath);
```